# How to indicate a field in domain class not to be created in the database

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a domain class like:

```
class Product {
   String name
   String number
}
```

and I only want name field be created in the database as a column, I will generate the number field in the code, I don't want it to be a column of the Product table in the database.

What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
class Author {
   String name
   String getUpperCaseName() { name.toUpperCase() }
   static transients = ['upperCaseName']
}
```

See http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/transients.html